# How does the Delay block work in Gnuradio

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I am reading the source code for block Delay in gnuradio,but I don't understand the following code.

```
std::memset(optr, 0, n_padding * d_itemsize);
std::memcpy(optr, iptr, n_from_input * d_itemsize);
```

It seems that they operate on the same pointer 'optr',0 is overwritten by the 'iptr'.
I want to add delay to my oot module,I need to know how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

They operate on the same pointer, but a different memory range. `std::memset(optr, 0, n_padding * d_itemsize);` sets `n_padding * d_itemsize`  number of bytes starting at `optr` to `0`.

The second one copies `n_from_input * d_itemsize` number of bytes from `iptr`.

I'm not familiar with the source, but hope that helps. It initializes a structure with 0, but fills the start of it with data from `iptr`. It overwrites only a part of the initial zeroes.

Comment: The effect of block delay is to insert zeros in front of the data.  In most cases,n_padding * d_itemsize less than n_from_input * d_itemsize.It looks that zeros was covered in next line,however it runs normally in gnuradio.